# sftp not working using expect

Tags: bash, sftp, expect

I am doing the sftp using a bash script, the script is running and it starts the sftp process and also completes it but it does not copy the complete data.( as my data size is approx. 600 MB it only copyies 800KB and terminates. the same is working fine when doing manually.

Below is my script  content

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=x.x.x.x
PORT=22
USER=abc
PASSWORD=password
SOURCE_FILE=/nobackup/file.gz
TARGET_DIR=/home

/usr/bin/expect<<!

spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST
expect "password:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
!
```

Please help.

Comment: This is an `expect` question, not a `bash` question. Expect is a TCL-based language, not in the POSIX sh family at all.

Comment: Also, overwriting `USER` is bad form -- on many (but not all) systems, you'll note that it already has a value, the current username. Part of the point of using lower-case names for your own variables (as recommended in the relevant POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- see fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace) is not overwriting system variables by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation of sftp allows a batch mode, why do you need the expect-script?

```
 .
 .
 echo "get $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR" | sftp -b - -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST
```

Comment: If installed `lftp` could be fine and probably preferable - but not installed on my system. Maybe the OP cannot install it, too?

Answer (score 0):

Consider [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/), which is explicitly built to be scriptable (and supports, among a great many protocols, sftp):

```
user=abc
password=password
host=x.x.x.x
port=22
source_file=/nobackup/file.gz
target_dir=/home

printf -v cmd 'open %q; get -o %q %q' \
  "sftp://$user:$password@$host:$port/" \
  "${target_dir}/${source_file##*/}" \
  "$source_file"

lftp -c "$cmd"
```

---

The `printf` generates a string akin to the following:

```
open sftp://abc:password@x.x.x.x:22/; get -o /home/file.gz /nobackup/file.gz
```

...which is a valid lftp script.

Comment: its giving the error:get: Access failed: No such file (/home/file.gz)

Comment: And does what you're substituting in place of the `/home` directory actually exist?

Comment: ... Which doesn't answer my question.